# Getting logback error when starting springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, logback

We have upgraded spring boot and spring cloud to latest version and we now see error when starting one of the services regarding logback configuration

Getting this error when starting application.
What property is the the error message referring too?

Starting the application now...
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.PropertyModelHandler - In  element, either the "file" attribute alone, or the "resource" element alone, or both the "name" and "value" attributes must be set.
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.PropertyModelHandler - In  element, either the "file" attribute alone, or the "resource" element alone, or both the "name" and "value" attributes must be set.
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:260)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:247)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="./build/run/logs" />
    <property name="KIBANA_LOGGING_PROFILE_NAME" value="kibana" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_LEVEL"
        source="logback.appLogLevel" defaultValue="trace" />
    <springProperty scope="context"
        name="LOG_LEVEL_DOMAIN" source="logback.appLogLevel.domain"
        defaultValue="debug" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_LEVEL_JWT"
        source="logback.appLogLevel.jwt" defaultValue="debug" />
    <springProperty scope="context"
        name="CLIENT_LOG_LEVEL" source="logback.clientLogLevel"
        defaultValue="trace" />
    <springProperty scope="context"
        name="ELASTIC_SEARCH_SERVER_URL"
        source="logback.elasticsearch.serverUrl"
        defaultValue="http://localhost:9200" />
    <appender name="Console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level)
                [%blue(%t)]
                %yellow(%C{1}): %msg%n%throwable</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ClientRollingFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/client-spring-boot-logger.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/archived/client-spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <springProfile name="${KIBANA_LOGGING_PROFILE_NAME}">
        <appender name="ElasticSearch"
            class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
            <url>${ELASTIC_SEARCH_SERVER_URL}/_bulk</url>
            <index>logs-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index>
            <type>tester</type>
            <loggerName>elastic-search-logger</loggerName>
            <errorLoggerName>elastic-search-error-logger
            </errorLoggerName>
            <connectTimeout>30000</connectTimeout>
            <errorsToStderr>false</errorsToStderr>
            <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
            <logsToStderr>false</logsToStderr>
            <maxQueueSize>104857600</maxQueueSize>
            <maxRetries>3</maxRetries>
            <readTimeout>30000</readTimeout>
            <sleepTime>250</sleepTime>
            <rawJsonMessage>false</rawJsonMessage>
            <includeMdc>true</includeMdc>
            <maxMessageSize>100</maxMessageSize>
            <authentication
                class="com.internetitem.logback.elasticsearch.config.BasicAuthentication" />
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>host</name>
                    <value>${HOSTNAME}</value>
                    <!-- <allowEmpty>false</allowEmpty> -->
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>severity</name>
                    <value>%level</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>thread</name>
                    <value>%thread</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>stacktrace</name>
                    <value>%ex</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>logger</name>
                    <value>%logger</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
            <headers>
                <header>
                    <name>Content-Type</name>
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </header>
            </headers>
            <filter
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>DEBUG</level>
                <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
            </filter>
            <filter
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                <level>TRACE</level>
                <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
            </filter>
        </appender>

        <logger name="elastic-search-error-logger" level="INFO"
            additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="elastic-search-logger" level="INFO"
            additivity="false">
            <appender name="ES_FILE"
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%msg</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </logger>
        <logger name="com.acme.application" level="${LOG_LEVEL}">
            <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearch" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>

    <logger name="com.acme.applicationclient"
        level="${CLIENT_LOG_LEVEL}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ClientRollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <springProfile
            name="${KIBANA_LOGGING_PROFILE_NAME}">
            <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearch" />
        </springProfile>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.acme.application.authentication.jwt"
        level="${LOG_LEVEL_JWT}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ClientRollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <springProfile
            name="${KIBANA_LOGGING_PROFILE_NAME}">
            <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearch" />
        </springProfile>
    </logger>

    <logger
        name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"
        level="TRACE" additivity="false">

        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="ClientRollingFile" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.acme.application.domain"
        level="${LOG_LEVEL_DOMAIN}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: remove ``` from end of config file

Comment: yeah sorry that was a typo when creating the question

Comment: i just tried your config locally, and it seem to work , can you also share your build file(gradle/maven) ?

Comment: thanks, it got solved. I am using latest version of logback.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the logback-elasticsearch-appender is no longer maintained and that the properties for elastic using the < property > is reserved.
Fixed by using fork https://github.com/agido-malter/logback-elasticsearch-appender

updated following:

```
<springProfile name="${KIBANA_LOGGING_PROFILE_NAME}">
    <appender name="ElasticSearch"
        class="com.agido.logback.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAppender">
        <url>${ELASTIC_SEARCH_SERVER_URL}/_bulk</url>
        <index>logs-%date{yyyy-MM-dd}</index>
        <type>tester</type>
        <loggerName>elastic-search-logger</loggerName>
        <errorLoggerName>elastic-search-error-logger
        </errorLoggerName>
        <connectTimeout>30000</connectTimeout>
        <errorsToStderr>false</errorsToStderr>
        <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData>
        <logsToStderr>false</logsToStderr>
        <maxQueueSize>104857600</maxQueueSize>
        <maxRetries>3</maxRetries>
        <readTimeout>30000</readTimeout>
        <sleepTime>250</sleepTime>
        <rawJsonMessage>false</rawJsonMessage>
        <includeMdc>true</includeMdc>
        <maxMessageSize>100</maxMessageSize>
        <authentication
            class="com.agido.logback.elasticsearch.config.BasicAuthentication" />
        <properties>
            <!-- esProperty was added for logback-1.3 compatibility -->
            <esProperty>
                <name>host</name>
                <value>${HOSTNAME}</value>
                <allowEmpty>false</allowEmpty>
            </esProperty>
            <esProperty>
                <name>severity</name>
                <value>%level</value>
            </esProperty>
            <esProperty>
                <name>thread</name>
                <value>%thread</value>
            </esProperty>
            <esProperty>
                <name>stacktrace</name>
                <value>%ex</value>
            </esProperty>
            <esProperty>
                <name>logger</name>
                <value>%logger</value>
            </esProperty>
        </properties>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <name>Content-Type</name>
                <value>application/json</value>
            </header>
        </headers>
        <filter
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
```